# How read only once object in range using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to know how can I read only once object in range if object shows many times in range. On this object I detect blobs, I count them if all blobs are in scope. I can not determine the exact location where object shows because objects are in diffrent position.

```
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    pictureWithRectangle = cv2.rectangle(frame, (250, 70), (500, 300), (255, 0, 0),
                                         1)  # obszar z którego odczytywac bede

    finder = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

    keypoints = finder.detect(pictureWithRectangle)

    picture = cv2.drawKeypoints(img_out, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    cv2.imshow('frame', picture)

    kropeczki = 0
    for dotes in keypoints:
        if (dotes.pt[0] > 250 and dotes.pt[0] < 500):  # oś x odczytanych kropek na zdjęciu
            kropeczki += 1
            if (kropeczki == len(keypoints)):
        # zrob cos
```

Comment: find the intersection area between two rectangles and if it's bigger than a certain threshold then ignore any one of them maybe smaller one

Comment: But in every cycle I get single frame and in the next cycle I dont have value from last cycle. How Can I remember this value?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. If you want to identify the same object in a different frame, you need to detect the region of the object and then match using features (eg. SIFT or any other). If it's a video, I guess tracking with mean shift algo. can help.

Comment: Yes, I recognize region of the object then I just read blobs. For better read I also used threshold and everything work properly :)